# Why does `sum += x` work the same as `sum += *x` for integer types? Is this an auto-dereference?

Tags: rust

Both the non-commented and commented code result in the same `sum` value. I'm not sure what's happening here, but I'm expecting the compiler to throw an error on NOT using a dereference.

```
fn main() {
    let a = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
    let mut sum = 0;

    for x in &a {
        sum += *x;
        // sum += x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not a case of auto-dereferencing. The `+=` operator (aka the trait `AddAssign`) is implemented for integer types (`T`) with both `T` and `&T` operands.

From the [`AddAssign` docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.AddAssign.html):

```
impl AddAssign<i32> for i32
```

```
impl<'_> AddAssign<&'_ i32> for i32
```